# Converting a Matlab function into a Python function

Tags: python, function, matlab

I am converting a Matlab script into a Python script and I have come across the following function:

```
function [y1]= hiper(muestras,x,xA,fs)
c=340
pot=2*ones(1,length(x));
dist=muestras*c/fs;
y1=sqrt(dist^2/4-xA^2+(4*xA^2/dist^2-1)*x.^pot);
end
```

The conversion I have done is as follows:

```
def hiper(muestras,x,xA,fs):
  c = 340
  pot = 2*(np.ones(1,len(x)))
  dist = muestras*c/fs
  y1 = np.sqrt( (dist**2/4) - xA**2 +(((4*xA**2)/dist**2)-1)*(x**pot) )
  return y1
```

I don't think I have converted this line correctly:

```
y1=sqrt(dist^2/4-xA^2+(4*xA^2/dist^2-1)*x.^pot);
```

specifically the `x.^pot` part.

Also, is the rest of my conversion correct?

Comment: It is hard to know what the MATLAB code does (or the Python code, for that matter) without knowing the types and sizes of the variables. How is the `hiper` function called in MATLAB? Is `xA` a scalar or an array? How about `muestras` and `fs`? Because of "`length(x)`" we can assume `x` is a vector...

Comment: @CrisLuengo xA,muestras and fs are scalars.

Comment: Then it seems to me you're doing the same thing. The way to know for sure is to run the function in MATLAB with a few different inputs, and take the responses as part of your unit test for your Python code (or run that test manually once to verify you did the translation correctly, if you're not writing unit tests).